# The range of a function of two variables

Tags: real-analysis

How would one go about finding the range of a function $f:\Bbb R^2 → \Bbb R^2$

I have the following function, $f\left(x,y\right)=\left(e^x\cos \left(y\right),e^x\sin \left(y\right)\right)$ and have been asked to find its range. How shall I start?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Given $(u,v)$, try to solve $\exp(x)\cos(y)=u$ and $\exp(x)\sin(y)=v$ (compute $u^2+v^2$ first)

Comment: So obviously $u^2+v^2=e^{2x}$
$\Rightarrow u=\sqrt{e^{2x}-v^2}=e^{x\over 2}\sqrt{e^x-sin(y)}$, but now I'm just stuck...

Comment: $u^2+v^2=\exp(2x)$ show first that $(u,v)\not =(0,0)$ is a necessary condition; and then $2x=\log(u^2+v^2)$ gives you $x$.  What are now your equalities for $\cos(y)$ and $\sin(y)$ ?

Comment: Firstly, $e^{2x}>0 \Rightarrow u^2+v^2>0 \Rightarrow (u,v)\neq0$.

This allows us to define $2x=log(u^2+v^2)$ which has domain $u^2+v^2>0$.

We have $cos(y)=ue^{-x}$ So $0<cos(y)<1$ since $ue^{-x}>0$. And $sin(y)$ has the same inequality? 

Am I on the right track?

Comment: In fact, you have $\exp(x)=\sqrt{u^2+v^2}$. So replace in the equations.

Comment: Replace what with what in what equations?

Comment: You want $\exp(x)\cos(y)=u$ and $\exp(x)\sin(y)=v$. As $\exp(x)$ has to be $\sqrt{u^2+v^2}$, the equations becomes $\cos(y)=\frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}$ and $\sin(y)=\frac{v}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}$. Why is there such an $y$ ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31049/discussion-between-vladimir-nabokov-and-kelenner).

Comment: Does this mean we have that $-1<{v\over \sqrt{u^2+v^2},1$

Comment: Put $\alpha=\frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}$ and $\beta=\frac{v}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}$. We have $\alpha^2+\beta^2=1$, so there exists $y$ such that $\cos(y)=\alpha$ and $\sin(y)=\beta$.